# Solving DIMACS 7 problems using MOSEK and YALMIP

Tags: numerical-optimization

I'm trying to test the MOSEK solver in the YALMIP MATLAB environment to try and solve a DIMACS 7 problem, but am having some issues. In particular, I'm trying to solve the "sched_50_50_orig" problem given near the bottom of the following link: http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Challenges/Seventh/Instances/. The following MATLAB code is used to solve the problem once the sched_50_50_orig.mat file has been loaded into MATLAB's memory,

```
options = sdpsettings('solver','mosek','verbose',1);
m = 4979;
x = sdpvar(m,1);

objective = c'*x;
constraints = [A*x == b];

optimize(constraints,objective,options);
x_opt = value(x);
```

Unfortunately, the above code gives me a primal infeasibility error instead of finding the optimal solution of 26673 given in the following link: http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Challenges/Seventh/Instances/tablestat.html. Any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Yalmip passes to Mosek is actually the dual problem. So what you see as Primal Infeasible status in Mosek log is actually a Dual Infeasible (i.e. unbounded) for the original problem. It is unbounded because you did not include the conic constraint, only the linear ones.

The actual representation of this problem is

```
objective = c'*x;
constraints = [A*x == b; x(1:2502) >= 0; cone(x(2504:2504+2472), x(2503)); cone(x(4978:4979), x(4977))];
```

and then is solves ok I think.

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks again for the solution. How did you know which constraints in the given data files were linear and which were conic? Looking at the data given I couldn't seem to work this out

Comment: @InquisitiveInquirer You have to find the Sedumi format documentation. The file contains something like 

`K: [1x1 struct] c: [4979x1 double] b: [2527x1 double] A: [2527x4979 double]`

K describes cones. `K.l` are linear cones (i.e. constraints of the form x>=0) and `K.q` are quadratic cones. And so on.